# How to figure from logs if solomining the wallet fails (linux)?

Tags: miner-configuration, linux

Is there a way to figure from logfiles if mining on a coin(d) ie bitcoind client on a linux OS fails?

Comment: Fails, or just doesn't succeed finding a block?

Comment: Lets assume there should be multiple blocks mined already. Isnt there a way to see from logfiles if something fails to credit mined blocks or what else can go wrong.